# Analytic continuation of Dirichlet series with sine in numerator

Tags: dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

The following Dirichlet series converges for $\Re(s)\in (1,\infty)$ (constant $k\in\mathbb{R}$), which is evident since sine function in numerator is in interval $[-1,1]$.
$$f_1(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{n}\right)}{n^s}$$

**How do we make analytic continuation of it for $\Re(s)<1$?**

I saw a quite complicated method how to make analytic continuation of $$f_2(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(2 \pi  k n\right)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\text{Li}_s\left(e^{-2 i k \pi }\right)-\text{Li}_s\left(e^{2 i k \pi }\right)\right)$$ using generalized polylogarithm function.

The second series differs from the first series by having $n$ in numerator instead of denominator inside sine function. And this fact seems to prevent using the same method.

Comment: Hint: consider, for all $p \geq 1$, $f_1(s)-\sum_{a=0}^{p}{(-1)^a\frac{(2\pi k)^{2a+1}}{(2a+1)!}\zeta(s+2a+1)}$. A term-wise bound shows that this function is actually holomorphic on an ever larger right half-plane (note that we therefore get a *meromorphic* continuation).

Comment: I can recognize series for $\sin (2 \pi  k)$ if it were without $\zeta(s+2a+1)$. How did you get this and how do you know it is equal to $f_1(s)$?

Comment: But it’s not $\sin{2\pi k}$ that you’re interested in, is it? Just expand the expression I’ve given you and use a Taylor-like formula/inequality to show that the series defines a holomorphic function as soon as $s+2p+1$ has real part greater than some numerical constant ($0$ or $1$, probably).

Comment: Your series converges really slowly for `k` as small as `k>8`. So they would be impractical even though in theory they converge on larger right half-plane.

Comment: You start seeing the convergence for $2a+1 > 2k\pi+\sqrt{2k\pi}$ so that’s no surprise. But you asked about analyticity and this expansion is a solution.